# Can reading /sys/block/$DEVICE/stat cause race condition?

Tags: c++, linux, race-condition

Each one second, my program reads /sys/block/$DEVICE/stat.

Substractes previously saved values, then saves current values. So I know hdd activity. 
But sometimes I've got too big values (between last and current) (5GB/second).

1. Can it be the race condition (if the kernel is writing to the file
   while application is reading it at the same time)?
2. Does any standard solution exists to avoid this situation?

   ```
   const int HDD_READ_POS     = 2;
   const int HDD_WRITE_POS    = 6;
   const int UNIX_SECTOR_SIZE = 512;

   std::tuple<uint64_t, uint64_t> hddStatus(const std::string &name)
   {
       std::ifstream in("/sys/block/"+name+"/stat");

       auto readVal_ = static_cast<uint64_t>(0);
       auto writeVal_= static_cast<uint64_t>(0);

       if ( ! in.is_open() ) {
           return std::tuple<uint64_t, uint64_t> (readVal_, writeVal_);
       }

       std::string line;
       std::regex rgx ( "\\d+" );
       std::regex_token_iterator<std::string::iterator> end;

       while (std::getline(in, line) ){

           std::regex_token_iterator<std::string::iterator> iter( line.begin(), line.end(), rgx, 0 );
           int pos_ = 0 ;

           while ( iter != end ) {

               if ( pos_ == HDD_READ_POS){
                   readVal_ = std::stoul( *iter ) ;
               }

               if ( pos_ == HDD_WRITE_POS){
                   writeVal_ = std::stoul( *iter ) ;
               }

               ++iter;
               ++pos_;
           }
       }

       return std::tuple<uint64_t, uint64_t> (readVal_, writeVal_);

   }
   ```

Comment: Regarding (1) - the kernel does not write to this file (or in fact any file in `/proc`, `/sys`, etc.). Rather, it generates the apparent contents of the file on demand when it is read. So there can be no race condition between the file being written and it being read. However, it's possible some internal kernel data structure that is read in order to generate the output may not be updated entirely atomically. And if that's the case, the kernel developers might be interested to know about it...

Comment: It happens one time in 6 - 7 days, so I wrote a small program (C ++) which read this file each millisecond, and also I ran a bash script which do the same thing. Trying to reproduce.

Answer (score 0):

Full list

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <regex>
#include <tuple>
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>
#include <cstdint>

const int HDD_READ_POS     = 2;
const int HDD_WRITE_POS    = 6;
const int UNIX_SECTOR_SIZE = 512;
uint64_t prevRead  = static_cast<uint64_t>(0);
uint64_t prevWrite = static_cast<uint64_t>(0);

std::tuple<uint64_t, uint64_t> hddStatus(const std::string &name="sda"){
  std::ifstream in("/sys/block/"+name+"/stat");

auto readVal_ = static_cast<uint64_t>(0);
auto writeVal_= static_cast<uint64_t>(0);

if ( ! in.is_open() ) {
    return std::tuple<uint64_t, uint64_t> (readVal_, writeVal_);
}

std::string line;
std::regex rgx ( "\\d+" );
std::regex_token_iterator<std::string::iterator> end;

while (std::getline(in, line) ){

    std::regex_token_iterator<std::string::iterator> iter( line.begin(), line.end(), rgx, 0 );
    int pos_ = 0 ;

    while ( iter != end ) {

        if ( pos_ == HDD_READ_POS){
            readVal_ = std::stoul( *iter ) ;
        }

        if ( pos_ == HDD_WRITE_POS){
            writeVal_ = std::stoul( *iter ) ;
        }

        ++iter;
        ++pos_;
    }
}

return std::tuple<uint64_t, uint64_t> (readVal_, writeVal_);

}


void init()
{

    auto values = hddStatus();
    prevRead  = std::get<0>( values ) * UNIX_SECTOR_SIZE;
    prevWrite = std::get<1>( values ) * UNIX_SECTOR_SIZE;
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
init();


while(true){

std::ofstream stat("statistics.txt", std::fstream::out | std::fstream::app);
if ( stat.is_open() ){    

        auto values = hddStatus();
        auto read  = std::get<0>( values ) * UNIX_SECTOR_SIZE;
        auto write = std::get<1>( values ) * UNIX_SECTOR_SIZE;

         // stat<<"Current Read: "<< read<<" Write: "<<write<<'\n';
        if (read > prevRead){
            stat<<"Diff Read: "<< read - prevRead <<'\n';
            std::cout<<"Diff Read: "<< read - prevRead <<'\n';
        }

        if ( write > prevWrite){
            stat<<"Diff Write: "<<write - prevWrite <<'\n';
            std::cout<<"Diff Write: "<<write - prevWrite <<'\n';
        }

        prevRead  = read;
        prevWrite = write;

        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(1));

    }
}

return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've reproduced this issue, and reported the [bug](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=196517)